# CodeIgniter + DOMPDF: Images don't appear when calling them in CSS

Tags: css, image, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I started to use DOMPDF in my CodeIgniter project to render some information in PDF.

Everything is OK when I display the information in html. But... no images were displayed in PDF, for the same HTML code (info: images used for background).

Except images, the other CSS info were correctly displayed (color, text-indent,...).

I tried the same 'kind' of code without using CodeIgniter, and the images were generated correctly.

Conclusion: Problem using DOMPDF in CodeIgniter.

Some ideas? I tried many 'random' combinations, but it still doesn't work. No google results for keywords 'CodeIgniter, DOMPDF, CSS, Images'...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you suing absolute URLs for the images?

Comment: Image loading problems can have a number of sources. To start it's important to know how you are loading the document into dompdf and how the images are referenced in the document/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more testing, I was able to add images:

- By writing the CSS inside the HTML code, using  tag.
- Use paths relative to the root directory, not the HTML file, like: ./assets/img/my_image.png

This worked for me, but I don't know why.